# Getting a drop down selection to direct users to a new page (MySQL && P4A Application Framework)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm working with the P4A Application framework and i have made a drop down selection box that allows users to select a location which when selected (and the continue button is pressed) takes the user to a new page (depending on the selection). Where i'm stuck is making a query in the database to get the ID of the location to direct users to the correct page, here is what code i have got:-

```
$this->build("p4a_db_source", "login")
    ->setTable("meetingrooms")
    ->load()
    ->firstRow();

    $this->build('p4a_field','location')
    ->setSource($this->login)
    ->setLabel('location')
    ->setType('select')
    ->setSourceValueField("ID")
    ->setSourceDescriptionField("MeetingRoom")
    ->setWidth(120);


    $this->build("p4a_fieldset","Book")
    ->anchor($this->location)
    //->anchor($this->booking)
    ->anchor($this->continue)
    ->setLabel('Meeting room bookings');
    $this->display("main",$this->Book);

}
public function change()
{
$location = $this->MeetingRoom->getNewValue();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM meetingrooms
    WHERE
            MeetingRoom = ?";
$row = p4a_db::singleton()->fetchRow($sql, array($location));

if ($row['MeetingRoom'] == "AreaOne")           
    {       
    p4a::singleton()->openmask("Area_One");
}
else 
{
    $this->setTitle("Process Failed");
{
    elseif ($location=="AreaTwo")
    {
        p4a::singleton()->openmask("AreaTwo");
    }
        elseif ($location=="AreaThree")
        {
            p4a::singleton()->openmask("AreaThree");
        }
```

I'm at a loss as this is the last bit of the application i need for the meeting room system (minus some very little details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is important, but there is a much better way to make this system using widgets and transferring them to active pages, check out the p4a link for details :)

[p4a](https://github.com/fballiano/p4a/wiki/FAQ) read around the docs for help

Answer (score 1):

Ignore it, its not important :)